# Dynamic hierarchy sitemap asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, hierarchy

Hi i need to build dynamic hierarchy sitemap . Here is my xml

```
<!--company tab-->
  <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx" title="Company list"  description="Company List"  >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyDetail.aspx" title="Company Detail Setup"  description="Company Detail Setup"  >
      <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDetail.aspx" title="Employee Detail Setup"  description="Employee Detail Setup" >
        <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDependentDetail.aspx" title="Employee Dependent Setup"  description="Employee Dependent Setup" >
        </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
  <!--company tab-->

  <!--Employee tab-->
  <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeList.aspx" title="Employee list"  description="Employee List" >
     <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDetail.aspx" title="Employee Detail Setup"  description="Employee Detail Setup" >
        <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDependentDetail.aspx" title="Employee Dependent Setup"  description="Employee Dependent Setup" >
        </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
```

sitemenu.aspx

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft New Tai Lue" 
                  Font-Size="0.9em" PathSeparator=" : " SkipLinkText="" Font-Bold="False" 
                  style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: small" 
                  Visible="True"  Enabled="false">
                  <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" Font-Underline="True" />
                  <NodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#284E98" />
                  <PathSeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#507CD1" />
                  <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#507CD1"  />

              </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

So nw is my question . In my company tab I can access to employee detail(**EmployeeDetail.aspx**) tab. In my employee tab i also can access to employee detail.aspx

but nw i get the error. **XmlSiteMapProvider requires that sitemap nodes have unique URLs.**

Any solutions?

Comment: I had that problem once and used URL Routing to solve it.

Comment: please give me example

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to post a comment to your question, but have you tried putting a querystring on the end of your employee detail links. It doesnt have to be anything that your code refers to explictly, just enough to make it different - eg:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDependentDetail.aspx?key=value1" title="Employee Dependent Setup"  description="Employee Dependent Setup" >
```

Comment: hi, thanks your comment. but I dont tink it can work for me. cos in my url I gt several querystring. I may get error which doesnt match the url

Comment: Sorry for slow response - you can dynamically change the siteMapNode at runtime - if you look at this link, it may help you assign the key/value pairs you need - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap.sitemapresolve.aspx